# Doing double derivative using tensor flow. Gets the error 'Tried to convert 'y' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported."

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am really new to python and hence tensor flow. Please explain to me how to do double derivative in python.

I am trying to learn machine learning.

sample of my code

```
 import sys
 sys.path.insert(0, '/content/PINNs/Utilities')

 import tensorflow as tf
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import scipy.io as sio
 from scipy.interpolate import griddata
 import time
 from itertools import product, combinations
 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
 from plotting import newfig, savefig
 import tensorflow.compat


 from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
 import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

 np.random.seed(1234)
 tf.random.set_seed(1234)
 class PhInNN :
    def __init__(self, X, u, layers, lb, ub):
      self.lb= lb
      self.ub= ub
      self.x= X[:,0:1]
      self.t=X[:,1:2]
      self.dd = self.x.shape[1]
      self.ff = self.t.shape[1]
      self.u = u
      self.layers = layers
      self.weights, self.biases = self.initialize_NN(layers)
      self.sess =
                  tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto
                     (allow_soft_placement
                     = True, log_device_placement=True))
                     self.lambda_1 = tf.Variable([0.0], dtype=tf.float32)
                     self.lambda_2 = tf.Variable([-6.0], dtype=tf.float32)
      tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
      self.x_tf = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.dd])
      self.t_tf = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.ff])
      self.u_tf = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 
                                         self.u.shape[1]])
      self.u_pred = self.net_u(self.x_tf, self.t_tf)
      self.f_pred = self.net_f(self.x_tf, self.t_tf)



   def initialize_NN(self, layers) :
     weights =[]
     biases = []
     num_layers= len(layers)
     for l in range(0,num_layers-1):
     W = self.xavier_init(size=[layers[l], layers[l+1]])
     b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layers[l+1]], dtype=tf.float32), 
                dtype=tf.float32)
     weights.append(W)
     biases.append(b)        
     return weights, biases

def xavier_init(self, size):
   in_dim = size[0]
   out_dim = size[1]        
   xavier_stddev = np.sqrt(2/(in_dim + out_dim))
   return tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], 
              stddev=xavier_stddev), dtype=tf.float32)

def neural_net(self, X, weights, biases):
    num_layers = len(weights) + 1
    
    H = 2.0*(X - self.lb)/(self.ub - self.lb) - 1.0
    for l in range(0,num_layers-2):
        W = weights[l]
        b = biases[l]
        H = tf.math.tanh(tf.math.add(tf.linalg.matmul(H, W), b))
    W = weights[-1]
    b = biases[-1]
    Y = tf.math.add(tf.linalg.matmul(H, W), b)
    return Y

def net_u(self, x, t):  
    u = self.neural_net(tf.concat([x,t],1), self.weights, self.biases)
    return u
def net_f(self, x, t):
    lambda_1 = self.lambda_1        
    lambda_2 = tf.math.exp(self.lambda_2)
    u = self.net_u(x,t)
    u_t = tf.gradients(u, t)[0]
    u_xn = tf.gradients(u, x)
    u_x = tf.gradients(u, x)[0]
    
    u_xx = tf.gradients(u_xn,x)[0]
    print(np.shape(u))
    print( np.shape(u_t))
    print(np.shape(u_x))
    print(np.shape(u_xx))
    r= u_t + lambda_1 * u *u_x
    rr=lambda_2 * u_xx
    f = r-rr
    print(f)
    return f



if __name__ == "__main__": 
  nu = 0.01/np.pi 
  N_train=1000
  layers = [2, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 1]
  data = sio.loadmat('/content/PINNs/appendix/Data/burgers_shock.mat')
  t=data['t'].flatten()[:,None]
  x=data['x'].flatten()[:,None]
  actual = np.real(data['usol']).T
  X, T= np.meshgrid(x,t)
  X_star = np.hstack((X.flatten()[:,None],T.flatten()[:,None]))
  u_star = actual.flatten()[:,None]
 #boundaries
  lb= X_star.min(0)
  ub= X_star.max(0)

 noise = 0.0
 dxi = np.random.choice(X_star.shape[0],N_train,replace=False)
 x_train=X_star[dxi,:]
 u_train = u_star[dxi,:]
 model = PhInNN(x_train, u_train, layers, lb, ub)
```

I need the value of `f` and `rr` but I am not able to compute. I feel the problem is in `u_xx`. When I print `u_xx` it shows `None`. I think this is because of the double derivative thing went wrong.

The data is from https://github.com/maziarraissi/PINNs/tree/master/appendix

I am trying to recode and learn.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a runable code.

Comment: @crazybrazilian Please check.

Comment: You should to debug your code an eager mode first and when it works convert it to graph mode. Try to find the operations that breaks the computational graph. Since I am not familiar to TF1, I cant really help you here. Are you constrained to use TF1? Since there is TF2. If needed I can provide you an example in TF2.